# Minimizing Volume of Solid

Tags: calculus, integration

I am hoping for some help with this question:

> The curve $y=sinx$ where $0\leq x\leq \pi$ is revolved about the line $y=c$ where $0\leq c\leq 1$ to generate a solid
>
> > (a)Find a value of $c$ that minimizes the volume of the solid. What is the minimum volume?
> >     (b) What value of $c$ in $[0,1]$ maximizes the volume of the solid?

Comment: **Hint:** Revolving $f(x)$ about the line $y=c$ is the same as revolving $f(x)-c$ about the line $y=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance from $y=\sin x$ to $y=c$ is the radius of the solid at a particular $x$-coordinate. Hence

$$V=\int_0^\pi \pi(\sin x-c)^2dx.$$

Expand this out and integrate (ignore the constant factor if you want); it's quadratic in $c$ so you should be able to minimize it with ease. (Remember, $dV/dc=0$ is a prerequisite for this.)